# Self hosted Integration Runtime fails on Sink but Auto Resolve (Default) Integration Runtime succeeds

Tags: azure-data-factory

Good day,
ADF v2 data loads that were working for months are suddenly failing on the Sink (to Azure SQL database) activity.

The error message points to a firewall entry for the target database:

> Check the linked service configuration is correct, and make sure the SQL Database firewall allows the integration runtime to access.

I have confirmed that the IP of my on premise integration runtime server is specified in the firewall rules of the Azure database.

When testing the linked service connectivity with the Integration Runtime parameter as '*AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime*' the test is successful but when setting it to my self hosted IR then I get the error message above.

Also, when the data factory job executes it, processes '*Lookup*' or '*Stored Proc*' activities to my Azure database without any problems (and I can see it uses both IRs at this point) but for '*Sink*' activities it fails and I can see it uses my self hosted IR at these points.

[image: both]

I have one IR node only and have confirmed it is active and running. It is also on the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - so the firewall engineer fixed it. Apparently the Azure database traffic was subject to general internet traffic firewall rule. The connection failed on MSSQL traffic so he created a firewall rule specifically for that and now it is sorted.